# bluetooth not working in lenovo B40-70?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

Bluetooth is not detected in lenovo b40-70 laptop in ubuntu 14.04. I have tried installing bluetooth manager and it shows bluetooth adapter not found.

My `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc   
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have also tried `rfkill unblock all` but nothing works... I do not want to switch to windows again as this laptop is giving me hell of a problems and this is one among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you may need to do is

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

I have one of these BT devices on my Lenovo and they can be difficult with firmware uploading to early during boot so please try the following

```
echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
```

Then edit /etc/rc.local

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And add the following above exit 0, as exit 0 must be the last line in the file

```
sleep 20
modprobe ath3k
```

save, exit program, and reboot

EDIT:A new kernel was released today that fixed the issue without the blacklist or the edits in rc.local.  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/ 
check `arch` to see if you have 32 or 64 bit system
You can delete the blacklist with `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf` and use `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and delete the `sleep` line and

```
modprobe ath3k
```

Save, exit program

For 32 bit, download and install

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.1-031901_3.19.1-031901.201503080052_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.1-031901-generic_3.19.1-031901.201503080052_i386.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/linux-image-3.19.1-031901-generic_3.19.1-031901.201503080052_i386.deb

For 64 bit

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.1-031901_3.19.1-031901.201503080052_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.1-031901-generic_3.19.1-031901.201503080052_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.1-vivid/linux-image-3.19.1-031901-generic_3.19.1-031901.201503080052_amd64.deb

I don't have hybrid graphics so I don't know if this kernel will cause problems

Comment: the first command gives this output   
E: Unable to locate package linux 
E: Unable to locate package firmware

Comment: does similar thing can be done to enable finger print reader in the same laptop

Comment: Don't know about finger print reader, but edited answer to correct the first command but you must have already had linux-firmware installed

Comment: it is not working again please help me, my friends mock for this for using ubuntu instead mac or win

Comment: Edit rc.local again using the command in my answer and change it from `sleep 20` to `sleep 30` save and reboot as a 20 second pause may be borderline